# Sencha Touch, JSONP, ASP.NET WCF REST and User Sessions

Tags: wcf, rest, sencha-touch, jsonp, session-state

Sorry for the rather ambiguous title but I'm developing a Sencha Touch mobile app and have built a REST-based WCF web service to supply the data and need to find out the best way to handle user logins and keeping their session alive throughout the app.

Now because I'm needing to use JSONP for connecting with the web service this limits the options for authentication and session handling. I could just save the user's credentials in local storage in the app and pass them with every call the service but this can't be the best solution. Some have mentioned passing the credentials to a login method on the web service and passing back a sessionid which is then sent with each further call. However I'm not sure how to create the session in the first place using WCF and how to keep it alive using the sessionid passed in.

Can anyone recommend a technique for achieving this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jsonp is a great trick to get data from a foreign service. But since you are the owner of the webservice, you could add an Access-Control-Allow-Origin: * header to the http response and switch to ajax mode. Then, you can use the standard authentication procedure.

Comment: Thanks @FidoX, I wasn't aware you could make the web service open to all domains using the Access-Control-Allow-Origin header. This is now in place so I can pass headers to the web service using normal ajax requests. My question still stands though about the best practice for persisting the user's session.

Answer (score 0):

If your webservice is aimed to be consumed by others developers the credentials will be configured in the client application  so I will use an authentication-key (like the google-maps api, for example) and let the webservice stateless.

If you need to authenticate against user/pass, the solution you propose is the same as http authentication. If you have no reason to reimplement yourself use the standard http authentication, if is available in your scenario.

Comment: The problem with using an api key is that the client is built in javascript so it wouldn't be secret. Anyone could look in the code, find the key and use it in their own application. For this app the user needs to be logged in to use it so it's not too much of an issue. Unfortunately basic authentication doesn't seem to work for REST-based WCF services returning JSON (unless there's something I've missed) so I will need to implement my own authentication. Probably checking the user's credentials and passing back a time limited session id for all further calls. Thanks for your advice.

Comment: Ok, Then, I think the user pass auth fit exactly with your needs. Doesn't need to be a BASIC auth, can be FORM oriented (using cookies) If it doesn't work in your framework you should investigate why. Im never used WCF but It's really strange that you can't use authentication in a REST service.